# Does the window class name change in win32api

Tags: winapi

Does the window class name you specify in lpszClassName ever change? E. g. for applications like firefox? Or is that name always the same for an application? SO once I installed Firefox, I can be sure that its classname doesnt change?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use spy++ to answer your question. .

Comment: After the window is created, no, it stays the same.  No such guarantees before, lots of programs generate the class name dynamically.  .NET does for example.  You find this out the Hard Way™

Comment: And to be clear with my comment I mean each application is different and they can change their code when they want. The class name wouldn't change once the window is created if that is what you are asking but if you are meaning will it change over time it could (up to the author). You might also consider searching by window title if you fear the class name might change but course the window title could change just as easily.

Comment: What do you want to do with the class name?

Comment: @andlabs I wanto bring the window to the front and I am doing this using findWindow and showWindow and findWIndow expects the window title or the window class name

Comment: @MikeCheel Thanks, man! I'd never heard of that programme!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can guarantee the class doesn't change is with some promise from the application developer. For example Winamp guaranteed its window class so you could use `FindWindow` on it for automation.

But there is nothing stopping an application from using a different class name for every window it ever creates.

Note that if you are trying to automate external applications, window class name is only one of countless moving-target problems. For example you get the window handle via `FindWindow`. You send it a `WM_COMMAND` for some command ID you found. Next version the application changes this command's ID. Same issue.